# Ionic 2 angular 2 get method works fine. But post method throws 400 Bad request

Tags: angular, ionic2

When we call get methos its showing results.

Same way when we try to login using post method API. Its throwing email and password can't be empty. Seems its http.post('url',params,headers); is not posting values. Can any anybody help me is there any headers need to pass extra or is there any config setting to make http.post works ?

```
 login(param) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/login', JSON.stringify(param),     options)
     .map((res: Response) => {
        if (res) {
            return { status: res.status, json: res.json() }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: add your post http request code in question

Comment: Could you also check what the actual request looks like? (In the chrome dev tools under "network")

Comment: updated post with post request.